# "insert into" statement with Excel comes up Syntax error

Tags: vba, excel

Experiencing problem with executing "insert into" statement

I try to run in Excel VB:

```
insertQ = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (Stockgroup, Stockcode, transdate, LastUpdate, time) VALUES ('990000', 'birthday', '21/12/2101', '','" & Time & "')"
```

but it shows up Syntax error.

It works if I take out last two fields

```
insertQ = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (Stockgroup, Stockcode, transdate) VALUES ('990000', 'birthday', '21/12/2101')"
```

have you come across this before?   @@

Comment: Change the word time to have brackets around. e.g. `[time]`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub sof20321516Insert2Excel()

  Dim strSQL
  Dim cnn, rst

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
    & ";Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;HDR=YES"""
  cnn.Open
'
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (Stockgroup, Stockcode, transdate, LastUpdate, `time`) VALUES ('990000', 'birthday', '21/12/2101', '','" & Time & "')"
  Set rst = cnn.Execute(strSQL)

'
' close ADO objects:
'
' rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing

  cnn.Close
  Set cnn = Nothing

  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Using ADO, the field name `time` should be anti-quoted. As in comments, the keyword time cannot be used as bare field name in SQL string.